# Tor Browser crashes when I use facebook

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

I hope someone can help me. I have used Tor only for Facebook since 1/1/15 when terms and conditions allowed them to spy into devices used to log into Facebook. At some stage Facebook kept blocking me from entry and then my use of core onion solved that. However the past 3 days I can log into fb BUT I can not post directly on my personal page OR any of the pages or groups I admin in. I can only share to them. I am unable to edit any of my shared posts to those pages once I have posted them either. Any attempt to do so immediately crashes TOR and it closes. However I can like, comment and edit on any and all other posts that are not under my admin control. I keep getting crashes and Tor Browser closing after I have moved through several pages on reloads. The only time it doesn't crash is if I stay on the home page so long as I don't try to post a status. I have checked for Tor updates and it says I have the latest. Does anyone know why this might be happening?? BTW I am not an IT whiz by any means of the imagination, so hope someone can simplify the answer if there is one. Cheers :) PS I forgot to mention that prior to 3 days ago I could also have multiple fb windows open and now if a second one is opened Tor Browser crashes again.

Comment: It's the same for me since today. I also have the last version.

Comment: Thanks user13258. At least I know that this is not isolated to just me. Please let me know if you find any solution to the problem :)

Comment: Hi I am experiencing the same issue. TOR crashes when I browse facebook. Hopefully it gets fix soon. Thanks!

Comment: @-user13258 An update came through today which solved this issue. Tor Browser has been updated.

Changelog:
Tor Browser 6.0.2 -- June 21
 * All Platforms
   * Update Torbutton to 1.9.5.5
     * Bug 19417: Clear asmjscache
   * Bug 19401: Fix broken PDF download button
   * Bug 19411: Don't show update icon if a partial update failed
   * Bug 19400: Back out GCC bug workaround to avoid asmjs crash
 * Windows
   * Bug 19348: Adapt to more than one build target on Windows (fixes updates)
 * Linux
   * Bug 19276: Disable Xrender due to possible performance regressions

Comment: I had the same trouble, the easiest solution is to download and reinstall the previous version (6.0), and then no more trouble !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue, there is a ticket for this: [#19400](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/19400).

The Tor Browser team is working on it and Tor Browser 6.0.2 will contain a fix.

Comment: Thank you canonizing ironize. I will get my IT savvy sons to check this out for me. I am not a computer whiz so do not have a grasp on the info but it certainly looks like it is the right ticket to assist me with my issue :D

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it may be a bug in tor browser (or firefox itself), so the only solution may be to wait for an update :(

Comment: Tor Browser 6.0.2 will be released in the next days and contains a fix for this issue.

Comment: Thank you @JensKubieziel the update arrived and the problem is solved (y)